# dyanmic drop down menu :D

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to make dynamic drop down menu in rails in the simplest way? For example I have two drop down menu, and the second one lists different things depending on the value on the first menu. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

GO through this it will help you in creating menus http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus